# Change UILabel color animated

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

How to change the color of the UILabel text gradually like the following [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vOYvaNhSHw)?
Can any one suggest me some code?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315148/how-to-animate-text-color-of-an-uilabel

Answer (score 2):

You can use formatted text.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(1,5)];
```

*iOS < 6*

Second you need to subclass UILabel and print this string inside the drawRect method. You need to create a some type of loop that changes the color according to the speech speed.

*iOS 6*

You can use the attributedTextproperty (no need to subclass)

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect

or reuse code:

https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSAtributedString` in `UILabel` from iOS 6.0. For lesser version below iOS 6.0 use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) which supports NSAtributedString

Change `attributed string` according to your `requirement` by `setting` it `again` in `UILabel`

**EDIT** add `colored text` as u want for example in loop

For 1st second in Label :  I am good boy.

For 2nd second in Label : **I** am good boy.

For 3rd second in Label :  I **am** good boy.

For 4th second in Label : I am **good** boy.

For 5th second in Label : I am good **boy**.

Answer (score 0):

here is one of my sample code. using block method of TTTAttributedLabel class it may help you .

```
        [cell.lblAtt setText:strAtt afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {

        UIFont *italicSystemFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        CTFontRef italicFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)italicSystemFont.fontName, italicSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);

        NSUInteger lenght = [[tempObj objectForKey:@"username"] length];
        NSUInteger lenght2 = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[tempArr count]] length];

        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[ThemeColor CGColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,lenght)];
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge UIFont*)italicFont range:NSMakeRange(0,lenght)];

        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[ThemeColor CGColor] range:NSMakeRange(lenght+11,lenght2)];
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge UIFont*)italicFont range:NSMakeRange(lenght+11,lenght2)];

        return mutableAttributedString;
    }];
```

Comment: it's not important, probably is an `UITableViewCell`... `lblAtt` is your label.

Comment: @prince cell is of tableview. lblAtt is its label.

Answer (score 0):

The app that you linked [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vOYvaNhSHw] , probably is maded using `cocos2d`.
In `cocos2d`, you can change text color easily also with animation.

Here an example:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5903

Here cosos2d sdk, i suggest to try, because it's very powerful:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

enjoy.