# Display a number in a label but have it count up the number

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` in my class and I would like the view to display the number but to count up to the number. For example, If the number was 368, it would climb quickly to the 250-300's then start to slow down as it gets to the number. Now this number will not always be 368, the number varies. It could be 6 or 129 or 1023 so it can't be a set-in-stone number. I obviously know how to create the `UILabel` as I already have it being used in my app, I just need help with counting upwards to it.

I have a "Player view", blah blah blah they get a score and it is passed to another view "Gameover view" and the score is display in a the `UILabel`.

Here is the code for the "Player view" to pass the data:

```
//finalScore is a int and so is currentScore
    second.finalScore = self.currentScore;
```

Here is the code for the "Gameover view" to pass the data:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // scoreLabel is the IBOutlet to the UILabel in IB for displaying the score.    
    self.currentIndex++;
    if(self.currentIndex == [self.numbersArray count]) self.currentIndex = 0;

    self->scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self->finalScore];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating a UITextView increasing or decreasing the value of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807849/animating-a-uitextview-increasing-or-decreasing-the-value-of-a-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I found this control and it works just as I need it to! [Click Here](https://github.com/Antondomashnev/ADTickerLabel)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the UILabel object in a loop, using the Timer. As time progresses at a certain interval, "slow it down" by adding on the difference in time. Sample code for updating a UI object via Timer is a common bit of code on the Internet, as it's the way you code progress bars.

[how to use the progress bar in the iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412795/how-to-use-the-progress-bar-in-the-iphone-app)

Comment: The only thing is, is I need the number as if is for the game I a built.

Comment: You're going to do the timer in another thread - and update the ui label as you go, much as the progress bar "progresses" as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Just call this method every certain interval (ex every 0.1 seconds), using a `NSTimer`

It will increment the value up to the target number.

```
-(void)countUp:(id)sender {
    int targetNumber = yourNumber;
    int currentNumber = [[myLabel text] intValue];

    // Calculate the increment for this time. Mess with this for different speeds. 
    // Just multiply some of the numbers by some constants (ex. 2) until you 
    // achieve the desired effect.
    double increment = (targetNumber - currentNumber) / targetNumber;
    NSString *newValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",currentNumber + increment];
    [myLabel setText:newValue];
    if ([newValue doubleValue] >= targetValue) {
        [(NSTimer *)sender invalidate];
    }


}
```

**For the timer:**

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:0.1 
                             target:self 
                           selector:@selector(countUp:) 
                           userInfo:nil 
                            repeats:YES];
```

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw change yourNumber to whatever represents the number that you want your label to eventually show.

Comment: I think I got it, I will do a test and let you know but I think this is the answer I need.

Comment: When the view shows, the number is just (in this case) 302.00000000 and did not count up

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw did you do `[myLabel setText:]` ? If you do, then delete that line because you don't want to do that because then it won't increment.

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw Also, I just changed something in my answer. Update your code for that. Also, I just realized that you may need to rewrite the increment calculation completely if it goes up to the wrong number. Im not sure how accurate it will be :/

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw On this line: `self->scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self->finalScore];` you need to start the timer as described in answer

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw In the method that is described in the answer, you need to change all references of targetNumber to self->finalScore and remove targetNumber's declaration.

Comment: Ok, and how would start the timer on that line?

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw See bottom of my answer.

Comment: Im am get the nsstring to nstimer alert.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38676/discussion-between-kyle-greenlaw-and-santa-claus)

Answer (score 0):

using literals it become quite easy to play

```
 UILabel * label;
 label.text = @(label.text.integerValue+1).stringValue;
```