# Animate UILabel with multiple sentences

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to animate uilabel to change text every 1 second.
But when i run the app, it directly shows the last word. I.e. i have 4 different sentences to display one after another but it directly shows the last one.

This is the code that I am using

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                             self.mapStat.alpha = 0.0f;
                             self.mapStat.text = @"Retriving Coordinates";;
                             self.mapStat.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.mapStat.alpha = 0.0f;
                         self.mapStat.text = @"Retrieved Coordinates";
                         self.mapStat.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.mapStat.alpha = 0.0f;
                         self.mapStat.text = @"Applying Coordinates";
                         self.mapStat.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.mapStat.alpha = 0.0f;
                         self.mapStat.text = @"Loading Map!";
                         self.mapStat.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }];
```

What is wrong with the code?
And is there any easier way to perform this animation?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with your code. What's wrong is that you, instead of reading the documentation, assumed that the `text` property of `UILabel` can be animated. It can't.

---

If you want to fade text in and out, you can use the `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` method of `UIView` and change the text in the completion block, after the label has faded out.

Comment: This answer, while correct, doesn't address the OP's desire to have one sentence fade into another sentence.  This can be accomplished using CATransition: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6267259/1445366

Comment: @AaronBrager The second part of the answer addresses exactly that, maybe you misinterpreted it.

Comment: Your solution would fade one out, then another in. I believe the OP is looking for a cross-dissolve.

Comment: @AaronBrager Aham. In this case, should the q/a you linked to be considered a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is you not set the delay for next animation in your code,you set delay time for complete previous animations,like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^
     {
         self.mapStat.alpha = 0.0f;
         self.mapStat.text = @"Retriving Coordinates";
         self.mapStat.alpha = 1.0f;
     }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
    }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:1.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^
     {
         self.mapStat.alpha = 0.0f;
         self.mapStat.text = @"Retriving Coordinates";
         self.mapStat.alpha = 1.0f;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
     }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:2.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^
     {
         self.mapStat.alpha = 0.0f;
         self.mapStat.text = @"Applying Coordinates";
         self.mapStat.alpha = 1.0f;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
     }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:2.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^
     {
         self.mapStat.alpha = 0.0f;
         self.mapStat.text = @"Loading Map!";
         self.mapStat.alpha = 1.0f;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int NoOfStringsLeft =  4;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
        target:self
        selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:Yes];

-(void)targetMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    //Update label text

     NoOfStringsLeft --;

     if(NoOfStringsLeft == 0)
     {
         [timer invalidate];
     }      
}
```