# UILabel appear in debug view hierarchy but not in the application

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have a UIView that I added in ViewController through the Interface Builder.

In my code, I create a label in this UIView every time that a button is pressed:

```
func addToDisplay(stringToDisplay: String) {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
    label.text = stringToDisplay
    label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.textAlignment = .Right
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    var lastLabel: UILabel?

    if displayView.subviews.count > 0 {
        lastLabel = displayView.subviews[displayView.subviews.count - 1] as? UILabel
    }

    displayView.addSubview(label)

    var viewsDictionary = ["displayView": displayView, "label": label]

    // add constraints
    if let lastLabel = lastLabel {
        viewsDictionary["lastLabel"] = lastLabel
        displayView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[label(==20)]-0-[lastLabel]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    } else {
        displayView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[label(==20)]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
    displayView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[label]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)) 
}
```

When I press the button, nothing appear on my device (nor on the simulator) but when I check the view debug hierarchy, it's there. I don't understand why. Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Here are two screenshots:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT2:**

Solved by changing alpha to something different than 0...

Comment: i think this happen because you not given proper constrain.    displayView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[label(30)]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)) Try like this

Comment: let me check this again

Comment: Won't `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` this be set to `true`?

Comment: No, I'm using Auto Layout on my Label, I have to set this to false otherwise those labels appear in the top corner left of my container view

Comment: clear one thing where is your button is it on displayView or on self.view? I think your display view is not at the front because when i try your code with self.view it work perfectly.

Comment: The buttons are laid out on the same level than the label container, which is self.view (the controller's view in Interface Builder)

Comment: It still doesn't appear on my device/simulator but in the view hierarchy it appears on the top right corner of the device, not in its container (which makes sense) so it's not because it's behind another view.

Comment: yes because your displayView goes behind some view

Comment: I don't have any view on top. Check on my update, I put some screenshots

Comment: try self.view .bringSubViewFront(displayView) in addToDisplay

Comment: No, it hasn't changed.

Comment: can you change your vertical space constraint add some 100 px spacing between the label and superview, Also can you share your nslog after updating the views?

Comment: I can see that the displayView get bigger but still nothing inside. The console output gets only a message saying that it "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint" (the one with the 100 px) but it wasn't there with "normal" 0 px spacing

Comment: I meant can you nslog the frames of the labels after applying constraints

Comment: do one thing give border to your displayView

Comment: ... I am a bit ashamed... I thought it was really weirs as I was sure to have set the correct auto layout so I decided to create this view programmatically and it worked. Then I thought that they might be something wrong in IB with my displayView then and that's when I realized alpha was set to ... 0! I don't know how, I might have set it by mistake. At least I realise that the debug view hierarchy doesn't take alpha into account. Sorry for wasting your time guys but thanks for your help.

Comment: btw, the easiest way to debug such kind of problems is using `po [self.view  recursiveDescription]` debugger command. You have to stop the debugger after layout (e.g. in `viewDidAppear`). Checking the view hierarchy visually is fine but checking the properties and frames of views in text form usually shows you the error much faster.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll have a look, just need to find out why `po` seems to not work anymore...

Comment: Thats great! But when you log a UIView, alpha is also mentioned in the log. Like this, `2015-04-18 14:16:33.505 MOPW[79905:8356851] <WeatherView: 0x7ffe3b4ef820; frame = (202 8; 110 30); alpha = 0; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffe3b4efb40>>`. If you had shared your log it would be easier for other to catch the error. Anyways, Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you need to tell the view to update constraints, write this and check:

```
[displayView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

Also test that your `displayView` is added to `self.view`!
Are you using **Navigation Bar**? If yes then is it `translucent`? If yes then your self.view may be starting from **(0,0)** and **Navigation Bar** is top of it. If this the case then give some **x & y**, say **(100, 100)** and check if it shows.

Let us know if this helped.

Comment: `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` doesn't change a thing. I'm not using a navigation Bar and the `displayView` was added to self.view through the Interface Builder. Check on my update, I put some screenshots