# UILabel animating number change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've got an UILabel that displays users score. And score changes from time to time, is there a way to animate this change, to slowly increment this number from its current value to its result value?
Something like http://josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/02/silverlight-animated-turbotax-number-display/ but for objective-c.

Comment: I found that might be helpful


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073520/setting-new-text-to-uilabel-and-animation


**First look for answer**

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, not exactly animation I'm looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a CADisplayLink to change the text property of custom subclass of UILabel over some period of time. You'll probably want to use a `NSNumberFormatter` for prettier output.

```
// Create instance variables/properties for: `from`, `to`, and `startTime` (also include the QuartzCore framework in your project)

- (void)animateFrom:(NSNumber *)aFrom toNumber:(NSNumber *)aTo {
    self.from = aFrom; // or from = [aFrom retain] if your not using @properties
    self.to = aTo;     // ditto

    self.text = [from stringValue];

    CADisplayLink *link = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animateNumber:)];

    startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    [link addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)animateNumber:(CADisplayLink *)link {
    static float DURATION = 1.0;
    float dt = ([link timestamp] - startTime) / DURATION;
    if (dt >= 1.0) {
        self.text = [to stringValue];
        [link removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        return;
    }

    float current = ([to floatValue] - [from floatValue]) * dt + [from floatValue];
    self.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (long)current];
}
```

Comment: Note, if you do use an `NSNumberFormatter`, create one of them and re-use it for every formatting job that uses the same format. Creating a new `NSNumberFormatter` is quite expensive, but re-using an existing one is cheap.

Comment: I keep getting EXC_BAD_ACESS at 
    `float current = ([to floatValue] - [from floatValue]) * dt + [from floatValue]`;

Comment: are you using properties for the `from` and `to` variables? and is it set to `retain`?  If you're not using properties do `from = [aFrom retain]`

Comment: It works great on simulator, but on iphone, it doesn't. It displays 1 number between "from" and "to", and then "to" number. Seems like it lags. Any advice?

Comment: works great on both simulator and device. awesome Jason. you rock!

Answer (score 4):

`AUIAnimatedText` has all you was asking for. That is replacement for UILabel with reach text animating possibilities ,