# Change label text for a few seconds before returning to original text

Tags: swift, uilabel

Basically I am trying to implement an animation that will replace a label's text for a few seconds before returning to the original text. I have managed to get the label to change text and fade out after 3 seconds, however I can't figure out how to return the text to the original state after the animation is complete.

Here is what I currently have:

```
    @IBAction func fade() {
    userMessageLabel.alpha = 100
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(3)
    userMessageLabel.text = "Name is not valid!"
    userMessageLabel.alpha = 0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

I need the text label to return to "Please enter your first name"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following class method on UIView would probably be the best way.   Once the animation finishes - if you provide a completion block that code will get executed.

In your example you could make the completion block, reset the text label to your desired value.

```
class func animateWithDuration(_duration: NSTimeInterval,
                animations animations: (() -> Void)!,
                completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)!)
```

Something along these lines would achieve the desired effect.   Within the completion block, you could have another animation.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { 
       userMessageLabel.text = "Name is not valid!"
       userMessageLabel.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {
       userMessageLabel.alpha = 1.0  
       userMessageLabel.text = "Please enter your first name" 
   })
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by using a delay:

```
userMessageLabel.text = "Name is not valid!" 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3) {
  userMessageLabel.text = "Please enter your first name"
}
```

My solution includes a slight simplification of the delay from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031137/how-to-program-a-delay-in-swift-3)

You seem to already know how to animate text to fade out or in.  If desired, add animation code into the `asyncAfter` delay function

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with **Swift3** from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073520/animate-text-change-in-uilabel/25890913#25890913) and it works perfectly!

**Objective-C**

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.label 
                  duration:0.25f 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                animations:^{

    self.label.text = rand() % 2 ? @"Nice nice!" : @"Well done!";

  } completion:nil];
```

**Swift 3**

```
UIView.transition(with: label,
              duration: 0.25,
               options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.label.text = (rand() % 2 == 0) ? "One" : "Two"
         }, completion: nil)
```