# How to program a delay in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, dispatch-after

In earlier versions of Swift, one could create a delay with the following code:

```
let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 4 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //put your code which should be executed with a delay here
}
```

But now, in Swift 3, Xcode automatically changes 6 different things but then the following error appears: "Cannot convert `DispatchTime.now` to expected value `dispatch_time_t` aka `UInt64`."

How can one create a delay before running a sequence of code in Swift 3?

Answer (score 1165, accepted):

After a lot of research, I finally figured this one out.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) { // Change `2.0` to the desired number of seconds.
   // Code you want to be delayed
}
```

This creates the desired "wait" effect in Swift 3 and Swift 4.

Inspired by a part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034838/5700898).

Comment: You could make your code a bit more swifty by replacing "+ 2" with "+ .seconds(2)". Or, for the ultimate in swiftyness, you could drop the first line and replace "deadline: when" with "deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)".

Comment: @OctavioAntonioCedeño Happy to help. This really bugged me for a while :D

Comment: if the delay is long, say 10 min, and the phone goes to sleep. the task will never be run even after the phone is woken up after 10 min.

Comment: @jiawen That's true, but that would be the case with any such delay. I can't think of a use case other than notifications where this could be an issue, and for waiting to send a notification you should definitely use `.firedate` instead.

Comment: but this function available iOS (10.0 and later)

Comment: @Ammaiappan Yep, it's working on iOS 10 + Swift 3. I'll check about iOS 11 and Swift 4 when they come out as final releases.

Comment: Working on iOS 11 and Swift 4!

Comment: I've got a problem with this answer, I wanted to trigger a code every second or less and it came out that it's not called exactly one second and there are discrepancies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347450/discrepancies-in-time-when-using-dispatchqueue-in-swift

Comment: @codddeer123 I suspect what's happening asynchronously may not be happening on time! The answer in your question there should explain more in detail.

Answer (score 217):

I like one-line notation for GCD, it's more elegant:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 42.0) {
        // do stuff 42 seconds later
    }
```

Also, in iOS 10 we have new Timer methods, e.g. block initializer:

(so delayed action may be canceled)

```
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 42.0, repeats: false) { (timer) in
        // do stuff 42 seconds later
    }
```

*Btw, keep in mind: by default, timer is added to the default run loop mode. It means timer may be frozen when the user is interacting with the UI of your app (for example, when scrolling a UIScrollView)
You can solve this issue by adding the timer to the specific run loop mode:*

```
RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```

*At this [blog post](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=67) you can find more details.*

Comment: plus one for the Timer comparison and the disclaimer about the main runloop!

Answer (score 60):

Try the following function implemented in **Swift 3.0 and above**

```
func delayWithSeconds(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) { 
        completion()
    }
}
```

Usage

```
delayWithSeconds(1) {
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: You basically just copied [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/5700898) but yes this is good, thanks.

Comment: How to cancel this?

Answer (score 14):

Try the below code for delay

```
//MARK: First Way

func delayForWork() {
    delay(3.0) {
        print("delay for 3.0 second")
    }
}

delayForWork()
```

---

```
// MARK: Second Way

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    // your code here delayed by 0.5 seconds
}
```

Comment: First way displays have error "Use of unresolved identifier 'delay'"

Comment: This programmer is working with a helper method in his code base and has for a long time.  So delay was code he has used for a while not knowing it is not apart of Apple's SDK.

Answer (score 7):

Most common things to use are `asyncAfter()` and `Timer`. But if blocking thread is OK, then there is an option:

```
sleep(3) // in seconds
usleep   // in 1/million of second
```

For asynchronous programming (Swift 5.5) pausing in func looks like this:

```
func someAsyncFunc() async {
    await Task.sleep(2_000_000_000)  // Two seconds
    // Code to be executed with a delay here
}
```

Comment: `sleep(3)` worked for me. Got a compilation error on `usleep`.

Comment: `usleep` needs and argument, of course, @AbdurrahmanMubeenAli. Something like `usleep(3000000)`.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` as a lot of people have answered.

Another way is to use `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)`. [More details here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-perform)

```
perform(#selector(delayedFunc), with: nil, afterDelay: 3)

@IBAction func delayedFunc() {
    // implement code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//Runs function after x seconds

```
public static func runThisAfterDelay(seconds: Double, after: @escaping () -> Void) {
    runThisAfterDelay(seconds: seconds, queue: DispatchQueue.main, after: after)
}

public static func runThisAfterDelay(seconds: Double, queue: DispatchQueue, after: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let time = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: time, execute: after)
}
```

//Use:-

```
runThisAfterDelay(seconds: x){
  //write your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UI can also use `Task` as shown in [MultiNodeTestConductor.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-distributed-actors/blob/b78ed6d16ab61e3c1fece7d8ed89b78f4be6f014/Sources/MultiNodeTestKit/MultiNodeTestConductor.swift#L141):

```swift
/// puse execution by the given druation
private func delayUiUpdate(duration: Double) async {
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(until: .now + .seconds(duration), clock: .continuous)
    } catch {
        logger.error("Task delay error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
await delayUiUpdate(duration: 2)
```