# Java delay without freezing UI

Tags: java, swing, timer, wait

In Java, I can use `sleep(x)` to delay some code from running for x seconds. But, if I'm using Swing, that makes my GUI freeze, so it's not an ideal solution.

**How can one create a delay before running a sequence of code in Java?**

Comment: How is your code set up?  Are you using the SwingWorker threads like you're supposed to? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: @Brick I'm not, as I'm making a very simple program and just trying to delay the change of a label (not of a heavy background task). I did figure it out myself, and I posted my own answer below.

Comment: This question is almost the exact same as [this popular question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031137/how-to-program-a-delay-in-swift-3/38031138#38031138), just that I'm talking about java instead of swift.

Comment: The canonical Swing solution is to use a Swing Timer. Your posted solution is overly complex, potentially dangerous in that it risks running Swing code off the event thread, and so should not be recommended as an answer on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you probably shouldn't be doing whatever you're doing
in the display thread. If it were in your own thread, the GUI
wouldn't freeze.  But short of revisiting your entire thread
strategy, the usual workaround is to add a queue of tasks to
be run later.