# How to show notification enable alert after some delay in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

In my app at the time app the launches first time there is an animation on first UIViewController for only 5 seconds. The problem is when app launches first time animation starts and Notification enable alert pop's up, so animation is hidden behind the notification enable alert and as soon as user tap ok on notification alert; animation ended. Because of this notification enable alert user can't see full animation. Please provide suggestion how to fix this ? Is there any way to delay notification enable alert to show after some delay ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your requesting authorization for notifications in your `didFinishLaunching` (or perhaps somewhere else). Where ever you're doing it just *move* it to the `completionHandler` of the animation and from there add a 5 second delay using [asyncAfter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031137/how-to-program-a-delay-in-swift-3).

Comment: How can i show push notification alert box after authentication or any specific page in IOS using react native

Comment: Sorry, I don’t much about react native