# select and unselect tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am going from tableViewControllerOne to tableViewControllerTwo. When this happens, tableViewControllerTwo scrolls to a certain cell. This works well, however, **I want the cell to be selected or "highlighted" after the scroll, and then become unselected/unhighlighted so it looks like the rest of the cells**.

After my segue, I have this statement called

    `tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)`

I tried doing this instead

    `tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)`

but the cell would remain selected. I also tried this

    `tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)`

but they must both happen so quick that I never see the cell become selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try delaying the `deselectRow` function in a way I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031137/how-to-program-a-delay-in-swift-3):

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
   tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```