# Set a delay after UIButton activation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, arc4random

I am working on a dice game that rolls 4 dice with random numbers assigned to each of them. When I press the roll button, the sound effect plays as intended and the images are replaced, but I am looking for a way to prevent the user from pressing roll until the sound effect is finished (maybe 2 seconds).

This is my function that updates dice images, where I have been testing this problem by adding `DispatchTime.now() + 2` to the if statements and before `arc4random_uniform`, but to no avail:

```
func updateDiceImages() {
    randomDiceIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    randomDiceIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    randomDiceIndex3 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    randomDiceIndex4 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    randomMultiplier = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))

    // determine the operator dice at random
    if randomMultiplier == 0 {
        addDice()
    }
    if randomMultiplier == 1 {
        subDice()
    }
    if randomMultiplier == 2 {
        divDice()
    }
    if randomMultiplier == 3 {
        multDice()
    }

    // image changes to random dice index
    diceImageView1.image = UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex1])

    diceImageView2.image = UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex2])

    diceImageView3.image = UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex3])

    diceImageView4.image = UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex4])

    multImageView1.image = UIImage(named: multArray[randomMultiplier])
}
```

If necessary, here is also my function that plays the sound effect, where I also tried implementing `DispatchTime.now() + 2`:

```
func rollSound() {
    // Set the sound file name & extension
    let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "diceRoll", ofType: "mp3")!)

    do {
        // Preparation
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch _ {
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
    }

    // Play the sound
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound)
    } catch _{
    }

    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Here is the implementation that I feel is the closest, but I get many errors:

```
    func rollSound() {
    // Set the sound file name & extension
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "diceRoll", ofType: "mp3")!)

        do {
            // Preparation
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch _ {
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch _ {
        }

        // Play the sound
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound)
        } catch _{
        }

        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031137/how-to-program-a-delay-in-swift-3?

Comment: Yes, that is actually where I got the advice to use `DispatchTime.now() + 2 `, I'll add that to the OP

Comment: Can you show how you are using it?

Comment: I just edited the post with my attempt at setting the delay

Comment: Try this code and LMK if that works: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26199273/

Comment: Awesome! It took me a minute because I typed it out instead of copy pasting, but it works great with `rollSound`. It still doesn't affect the image changing, I assume that I can use the same functionality in my `updateDiceImages` function?

Comment: Yes you need to add same in your `updateDiceImages` and if it works I will post my answer.

Comment: works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated code for your error.

```
func rollSound() {
    // Set the sound file name & extension
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "diceRoll", ofType: "mp3")!)

        do {
            // Preparation
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch _ {
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch _ {
        }

        // Play the sound
        do {
            self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound)
        } catch _{
        }

        self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        self.audioPlayer?.play()
    }
}
```

You need to add `self` to the property if you want to use class instance into `DispatchQueue` closer. and same for `updateDiceImages()`

Comment: Happy to help you..:)