# How to add animation delay in Modal View presentation swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation

```
@objc func popCartView(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let modalViewController = CartViewController()
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How to animate this view with more time like 2 seconds to complete animation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to program a delay in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031137/how-to-program-a-delay-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@objc func popCartView(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let modalViewController = CartViewController()
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        // Your code with delay
        self.present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```