# Swift - Run 1000 async tasks with a sleeper after every 50 - how to communicate btw DispatchGroups

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, dispatchgroup

I have to run 1000 async calculations. Since the API has a limit of 50 requests/min I have to split it up into chunks of 50 and wait for a minute after processing once chunk. Eventually I want to print the results.

```
resultsArray = [Double]()
// chunked is an extension
points.chunked(into: 50).forEach { pointsChunk in
    pointsChunk.forEach { pointsPair
        // this function is async
        service.calculate(pointsPair) { result in
            resultsArray.append(result)
        }
    }
    // wait for a minute before continuing with the next chunk
}

// after all 1000 calculations are done, print result
print(resultsArray)
```

I did try finding a solution with using `DispatchGroup` but struggled on how to incorporate a timer:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "MyQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
let chunkGroup = DispatchGroup()
let workGroup = DispatchGroup()

points.chunked(into: 50).forEach { pointsChunk in
   chunkGroup.enter()
   pointsChunk.forEach { routePointsPair in
        workGroup.enter()
        // do something async and in the callback:
        workGroup.leave()
   }
   workGroup.notify(queue: queue) {
      do { sleep(60) }
      chunkGroup.leave()
   }
}

chunkGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print(resultArray)
}
```

This just executes all chunks at once instead of delayed by 60 seconds.

Comment: You can add a timer to a Dispatch queue, see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031137/how-to-program-a-delay-in-swift-3

Comment: what is this .chunked? an extension? I think it would be beneficial for you to start learning about RxSwift.

Comment: @EarlGrey yes, chunked is just an extension that splits the array into chunks of size n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have implemented in a similar situation is manual suspending and resuming of my serial queue.

my queue reference:

```
public static let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.queue.MyProvider.Serial")

func serialQueue() -> DispatchQueue {
    return MyProvider.serialQueue
}
```

suspend queue:

```
func suspendSerialQueue() -> Void {
    self.serialQueue().suspend()
}
```

resume queue after delay:

```
func resumeSerialQueueAfterDelay(seconds: Double) -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
        self.serialQueue().resume()
    }
}
```

This way I have full control over when I suspend and when I resume the queue and I can spread out many API calls evenly over longer period of time.

```
self.serialQueue().async {

  self.suspendSerialQueue()
  // API call completion block {
     self.resumeSerialQueueAfterDelay(seconds: delay)
   }
}
```

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but maybe you can adapt my example to your needs.