# Why is a strong reference cycle possible with NSNotificationCenter but not UIView.animateWithDuration?

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting, strong-references

With a NSNotificationCenter block, I have to use [unowned self] to avoid a strong reference cycle:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    .addObserverForName(UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification,
        object: nil,
        queue: nil,
        usingBlock: { [unowned self] (notification : NSNotification!) -> Void in
            self.add(123)
        })
```

However, in UIView.animateWithDuration, I do not have to use [unowned self]:

```
   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
      self.someOutlet.alpha = 1.0
      self.someMethod()
   })
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference between the animation block and the notification center block is that the animation block is extremely short-lived—it is executed immediately and then released.

In both cases, the blocks will capture `self`; but only the `NSNotificationCenter` code is problematic because the notification center will hold a reference to the block indefinitely, since the notification can happen at any time.

Note that this is different than a circular reference. A circular reference is often created by an object holding a reference to a block that captures self, like this:

```
self.myBlock = {
   self.doSomething()
}
```

That circular reference means that `self` will never be deallocated. The notification center isn't a circular reference (since self doesn't hold a reference to the notification center), it's just a regular reference that will be held until the observer is removed.

Answer (score 1):

The `animations: () -> Void` and `completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?` blocks for a UIView Animation do not retain a reference to self. This previous post is very informative on the topic

[Do we need to use __weak self inside UIAnimationBlocks in ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770743/do-we-need-to-use-weak-self-inside-uianimationblocks-in-arc)

The notification block `(NSNotification) -> Void` does retain a reference to self, by passing it in as unowned in your case, it should not increment the retain count. I try to ensure I use either unowned, or weak, on any reference I pass into the closure. There is a great post about this found here http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift

But, I highly recommend staying away from using Notifications, especially with blocks, as there maybe a bug pointed out by this article, which was shocking when I read it.

http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsnotificationcenter-with-blocks-considered-harmful/

Comment: Whoa that's crazy, so it's only because of a Cocoa bug I have to do this?

Comment: @TruMan1The answer I provided only highlighted an issue with the notification center. The true reason is that you want to avoid creating a strong reference cycle, I updated my answer to reflect that