# Does a block need to weakify self if only method call is initiated in the block?

Tags: objective-c

If a block is only using self to call a method, is it necessary to weakify it to prevent retain cycle?

This is not a duplicate of another post, I am not asking if this needs to be done within UIView animation block, but whether it needs to be done when self block is only calling method call. I have added a dispatch_async example as well.

```
@weakify(self);

// Need to strongify?
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    @strongify(self);
    [self doSomething];
});

// Need to strongify?
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.125 animations:^{
    @strongify(self);
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: You don't need weak references in `UIView` animation blocks. There is no strong reference cycle here.

Comment: @Rob Does the use of self to call a method create a reference to self?

Comment: No @Boon, it's because for there to be a cycle, self needs to retain the block -- either directly or indirectly.  The block retains self, but self does not retain the block.

Comment: Yes, you need the reference to self to call the method.  Think of the call as taking an extra argument (the self).

Comment: Just to clarify (danh is right) There is no cycle, but there is a reference to self in the block

Comment: Thanks - can one of you answer the question with the proper info and I will select.

Comment: @Rob So would you say only when the block is initiated by self (or property of self) does it need to use weakify/strongify?

Comment: No. You need to use weak reference to self if the block is going to (potentially) outlive `self` (or, more critically, if you have a strong reference cycle). `UIView` block-based animations are a bit of a special case. There certainly is no strong reference cycle here and the animation engine is quite clever about handling the blocks for dismissed views. Even if you have a completion handler in your animation, it's getting resolved when the scene is dismissed. Now, if you were doing asynchronous network requests or the like, you'd have to be more diligent. But not with `UIView` animations.

Comment: @Rob Thank you - very good info. So with dispatch_async, you would need to then? Can you leave your answer below - I will pick as the right answer.

Comment: So, yes, if you use `dispatch_async` it could be a problem (though it would be resolved as soon as the `dispatch_async` fires, so its often of neglible concern). Where it's really problematic is with repeating timers or anything asynchronous that might take a lot of time. Or strong reference cycles. Then it's definitely a problem. Just not `UIView` block-based animations. Thanks for the offer, but given this has been marked as duplicate, no, I can't leave an answer.

Comment: @Rob This is not a duplicate - it was marked erroneously because the example happened to use animation block. I have added dispatch_async as another example.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you don't need to weakify, because the block is not retained by self. So there is no retain cycle.

[Do we need to use __weak self inside UIAnimationBlocks in ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770743/do-we-need-to-use-weak-self-inside-uianimationblocks-in-arc)