# Animate WKInterfaceLabel with text change apple watch swift

Tags: ios, animation, apple-watch, watchos-2, wkinterfacelabel

I am working on an apple watch application. In the application, I have a view where the user may swipe left and right between 3 given results. I am using WKInterfaceLabel to show result information. On each swipe, labels are updated with new text.

View screenshot:

[image: Results screen]

I want to animate the change of text on swipe. How can I do this?

Any help provided will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand you right that you have a single page, and you want to change the content of the label by swiping left and right?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner yes, you are right.

Comment: Have you tried to add a `WKSwipeGestureRecognizer`(docu [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkswipegesturerecognizer)) to your page?

Comment: I am using that for swipe but I want to add animation effect on the change of text for labels.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand this. But what kind of animation do you imagine?

Comment: I don't have any specific animation requirement but move in move out animation will work. This might give you some idea about animations I am looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073520/animate-text-change-in-uilabel

Answer (score 2):

This is not very elegant, but it should work:
You can fade out  the contents of a `WKInterfaceLabel`, and fade in another label in its place. So, place 2 `WKInterfaceLabel` objects at the same place. One of them is visible (`alpha` = 1.0) and the other invisible (`alpha` = 0.0).
When you swipe, determine the new value that should be shown, and set it to the invisible label.
Then, animate the transition using the function `animate(withDuration:animations:)` of the `WKInterfaceController`. In the animation block, change the `alpha` values as required, something like

```
animateWithDuration(1.0) {
    self.visibleLabel.setAlpha(0.0)
    self.invisibleLabel.setAlpha(1.0)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got that. It is kind of workaround but it will work. Nice idea though. Thanks!

Comment: I will award bounty in the grace period. I will wait if I get an any better solution. Hope you understand!

Comment: No problem! And, of course, it is enough to change the alpha value of the upper label...

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work out so well. Do you have any more suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:-

```
 func labelimage(img: UIImageView) {
        print(labelrate.hidden)
        if (labelrate.hidden) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.labelrate.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.labelrate.alpha = 0
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        self.labelrate.hidden = !self.labelrate.hidden
    }
```

Comment: I am doing this work in watchOS and uiimageview and uiview are not available in watchOS. Can you provide any other solution? Also, what is labelrate? And why are you passing img in function?